# A problem occurred configuring project ':webview_flutter_android'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview-flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable, create a new project and only import `webview_flutter ^3.0.4`
2. `flutter run` with Android Simulator (Nexus device 5x API 28 Android 9.0)

**Error:**

```dart
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':webview_flutter_android:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31.
     Required by:
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.2.1 > com.android.tools:common:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.2.1
         project :webview_flutter_android > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.2.1
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.31.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > Remote host terminated the handshake
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
```

I have upgraded from JDK8 to JDK18, but the problem is still there

But on iOS, everything is all right.

#### My environment:

```dart
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale en-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability


java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```